# Is there a typed SKI calculus?

Tags: reference-request, logic, lambda-calculus, type-theory, combinatory-logic

Most of us know the correspondence between [combinatory logic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combinatory_logic) and [lambda calculus](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambda_calculus). But I've never seen (maybe I haven't looked deep enough) the equivalent of "typed combinators", corresponding to the simply typed lambda calculus. Does such thing exist? Where could one find information about it?

Comment: You might be interested in _The Reader Monad and Abstraction Elimination_ in [The Monad.Reader, Issue 17](https://themonadreader.wordpress.com/2011/01/09/issue-17/). The Reader monad (or more precisely its applicative functor) is closely related to typed SKI.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The expressive completeness of the typed combinators compared to the simply typed lambda calculus has been [demonstrated](http://www.emis.de/journals/NSJOM/Papers/23_1/NSJOM_23_1_319_329.pdf). For each untyped combinator, one needs a whole family of typed combinators. For example, one has

- $\mathbf{I}_{\alpha\to\alpha}$
- $\mathbf{K}_{\alpha\to(\beta\to\alpha)}$
- $\mathbf{S}_{\alpha\to(\beta\to\gamma)\to(\alpha\to\beta\to(\alpha\to\gamma))}$

for all combinations of simple types $\alpha,\beta$ and $\gamma$.

Alternatively, just think of the types as type schemes (or polymorphic types) and enter them into Haskell and voila: [combinators](http://logicaltypes.blogspot.com/2008/08/combinators-in-haskell.html).

Comment: I never thought of the $\mathbf{S}$ combinator as acting over a Monad! Is that so?

Comment: Actually, I've been pointed out that $\mathbf{S}$ corresponds to the `<*>` operator of Applicative Functors, and `pure` the $\mathbf{K}$.

Comment: $\mathbf{S}$ is quite fundamental, so it could correspond to many things. $\mathbf{S}$ has the same type as the monad function $ap$ for functor $\Lambda X.\alpha\to X$.